# data truncated for column in SOAP webservice

Tags: delphi

I have a form in which I make a ticket to give to the client. The problem is in button "make ticket", which calls function hacerticket on the server:

```
var
ticket:Isucursales1.Tticket;
venta:Isucursales1.Tventa;


begin
      ticket:=Isucursales1.Tticket.Create;
      venta:=Isucursales1.Tventa.Create;

           with Unit1.datos.cdsticket do
            begin
              Open;
              Insert;
          //   datos.nuevoticket.ExecSQL;
              //FieldByName('idticket').AsInteger:=4;
             FieldByName('numero').AsInteger:=1;
              FieldByName('importe').AsFloat:=StrToFloat(Form3.StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]);
              FieldByName('fechae').AsDateTime:=Now();
              FieldByName('horae').AsDateTime:=Now();
              FieldByName('idsucursal').AsInteger:=1;
            end;
               with ticket do
                  begin

                   numero:=1;
                   importe:=StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]);
                   fechae:=Unit1.datos.cdsticket.FieldByName('fechae').AsString;
                   horae:=Unit1.datos.cdsticket.FieldByName('horae').AsString;
                         idsucursal:=1;
                  end;
                  GetIsucursales.hacerticket(ticket);
                while not Grillaticket.DataSource.DataSet.Eof do
                  begin
                     with venta do
                      begin
                        idproducto:=Grillaticket.DataSource.DataSet['idproducto'];
                        cantidad:=Grillaticket.DataSource.DataSet['cantidad'];
                        GetIsucursales.ventas(venta);
                      end;
                  end;

end;
```

in the server:
procedure Tsucursales.hacerticket(ticket:Tticket);

```
begin
  consultas:=Tsucursallaferretera.Create(nil);
  with consultas.queryticket do
    begin
      SQL.Add('insert into ticket(numero,importe,fechae,horae,idsucursal)');
      SQL.Add('values (:numero,:importe,:fechae,:horae,:idsucursal);');
           ParamByName('numero').AsInteger:=ticket.numero;

      ParamByName('importe').AsFloat:=ticket.importe;
      ParamByName('fechae').AsString:=ticket.fechae;
      ParamByName('horae').AsString:=ticket.horae;
            ParamByName('idsucursal').AsInteger:=ticket.idsucursal;
       ExecSQL();

    end;
end;
```

the problem is "Data truncated for column numero" numero is an integer and I am intending with 1 (is not a unique field, I mean it can be whatever value).

I also tried with F4 and values are incoming correctly.

Please help me!

Well i have tried removing field numero from server(the second code above) and i obtain:
Data truncated for column  "importe"; Probably problem is on the id idticket or in the insertion.

Comment: What DB you are using? What DDL of the table ticket? "Data truncated" error can be caused if the value bigger then field can store. For example 'abcd' for field declared as varchar(3) or 999999 for numeric(5)...

Comment: i am assigning a static value "1" and the field is integer INT(11);    Here you are: `code`create table ticket(
idticket integer not null primary key auto_increment,
numero integer,
importe decimal(10,2),
fechae date,
horae time,
idsucursal integer,
foreign key (idsucursal) references sucursal(idsucursal)
); `code`

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on the DB? Does that work? The component set you are using for the DB connection and the target database type (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, etc) are important.

Comment: @Graymatter i try with an insert in mysql workbench with just a number as "1", and i am using zeoslib components, thank for commenting